# Model a function with specific shape

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I need a function with a specific shape:

- Quadratic/gaussian concave shape ($-x^2$ like)
- Centered in $\frac{1}{2}$ where it reaches the max value 1
- On `0` and `1` to become null

I first tried using a second-degree polynomial function and I failed.
By repeated tries on `graph.tk`, after I deduced on paper that $c=0$, I got $-4x^2+4x$ to be what I need.

Then I found the function $e^{-x^2}$ which have a very nice shape.
But now I have to span it in $[-0.5, 0.5]$ and add an offset.
$e^{-(x-0.5)^2}$ is centered in $\frac{1}{2}$ where it reaches 1, but it does not descend down to zero in `0` and `1`.

I'm interested in either the solution to this problem and in the process of reaching that solution. How is this usually done?

---

If Q above is unclear:

How do I model $e^{-x^2}$ to meet the requirements in bullets above?

Comment: do you want it to drop sharply at $0$ and $1$ (like the quadratic does) or do you want it to go smoothly (i.e slope goes to zero at these points)? And are piecewise definitions okay?

Comment: I guess a 4th  degree polynomial would do the trick with the right coefficients (and the right $y$ offset to make it have only 2 roots : $0$ and $1$)

Comment: @RobertMastragostino: I need it to reach 0 (any slope). I'd prefer it in one piece.

Comment: @Dolma: I added a more concise and clear question

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by modelling $e^{-x^2}$, but you might try a function like $$f(x) = \exp\left(4-\frac{1}{x(1-x)}\right).$$ Here's a graph: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%284-1%2F%28x%281-x%29%29%29+from+0+to+1

Comment: @Abel: Very nice, thanks. (I was using the wrong plotter). It's actually very nice because it descends slowly to 0.

Comment: @iuliux That's the idea. Your plotter is right that the function is not strictly defined for $x=0$ or $x=1$, but you can just define it to be zero there and it will still be smooth.

Comment: @Abel : No it's not. The function $f$ you've written will always be $>0$ so if you set for any $x$, $f(x)=0$ it will not be smooth anymore, there will be a discontinuity at that point.

Comment: @Dolma Yes it is. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 1} f(x) = 0$ even though $f(x)>0$ for $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @Abel: Oh yes you're clearly right I'm sorry, I didn't look at your function correctly ... my bad ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you're almost there. You have your nice function centered on $x=\frac{1}{2}$:

$$f(x)=e^{-(x-\frac{1}{2})^2}$$

Now you can compute $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ which will be equal because $f$ is symmetric around $x=\frac{1}{2}$:

$$\large f(0)=f(1)=e^{-\frac{1}{4}}$$

If you want $f(0)=f(1)=0$ you just have to write:

$$f(x)=e^{-(x-\frac{1}{2})^2}-e^{-\frac{1}{4}}$$

But now for $x=\frac{1}{2}$, your function is equal to $\large1-e^{-\frac{1}{4}}$

Just multiply it by $\large\frac{1}{1-e^{-\frac{1}{4}}}$ and here you go:

$$\large f(x)=\frac{e^{-(x-\frac{1}{2})^2}-e^{-\frac{1}{4}}}{1-e^{-\frac{1}{4}}}$$

Here's the plot of this function:

[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks. It turned out to look an awful lot like the quadratic. :)